# How can I match all single elements or pairs in a data frame with a group in another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, igraph

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| Groups | elements | p |
| --- | --- | --- |
| animals | cat,dog,bird | 1 |
| furniture | chair,table | 2 |
| vehicles | car,motorcycle | 3 |
| House | animals,furniture | 4 |
| Commute | bike,rollers | 5 |
| Food | pasta,pizza | 6 |
| Need | water,power | 7 |
| Family | House,Mother | 8 |

the column groups contain all the groups and the hyper groups.For example animals is a group. But House is a hyper group that within contain the groups animals and furniture.
The other hyper group is the Family which contains the hyper group House plus the Mother. So this is my universe with all the possible groups and hyper groups according the elements that I have. The third column "p" contain the value that corresponds to each group or hyper group that I need to implement a function later.

Now I take the first 3 days of a month :

| date | var1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | cat |
| 2022-01-01 | cat |
| 2022-01-01 | cat |
| 2022-01-02 | cat,Mother,bike,pasta |
| 2022-01-02 | cat,Mother,bike,pasta |
| 2022-01-02 | cat,Mother,bike,pasta |
| 2022-01-03 | dog,bird |
| 2022-01-03 | dog,bird |
| 2022-01-03 | dog,bird |

Ideally I want the reported data frame to look like this :

| date | var1 | Groups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | cat | NA |
| 2022-01-01 | cat | NA |
| 2022-01-01 | cat | NA |
| 2022-01-02 | cat,Mother,bike,pasta | Family |
| 2022-01-02 | cat,Mother,bike,pasta | Family |
| 2022-01-02 | cat,Mother,bike,pasta | Family |
| 2022-01-03 | dog,bird | animals |
| 2022-01-03 | dog,bird | animals |
| 2022-01-03 | dog,bird | animals |

How can I implement this in R ?

The groups data frame:

```
Groups = c("animals","furniture","vehicles","House",
         "Commute","Food","Need","Family")
elements = c(c("cat,dog,bird"),c("chair,table"),c("car,motorcycle"),c("animals,furniture"),
         c("bike,rollers"),c("pasta,pizza"),c("water,power"),
         c("House,Mother"))
p = seq(1,8,1)
data = tibble(Groups,elements,p);data
```

and the sample data frame

```
date = c(rep(as.Date("2022/1/1"),3),
         rep(as.Date("2022/1/2"),3),
         rep(as.Date("2022/1/3"),3))
var1 = c(rep("cat",3),rep("cat,Mother,bike,pasta",3),rep("dog,bird",3))

df = tibble(date,var1);df
```

Any idea of how can I combine the two data frames ;

Comment: You mention what you would like your result to be, but you don't really explain how to get from your input to your output, and I personally don't see the logic in it. For example, why do the rows with cat have NA in group if cat can be found in the animals group?

Comment: @Alexis because cat alone cannot activate the group animals.Needs another member of the group animals like dog and bird.

Comment: Why is "cat,Mother,bike,pasta" reported as "Family"?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding because cat is in the group animals that is member of the group house that needs the Mother to activate the Hyper group

Comment: So you're looking for the lowest level group that can contain all the items in your list?

Comment: @DanAdams actually for the higher level of group if there more than one elements in var1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `igraph` would be a nice helper for your question, since a visualization of memberships in `data` can be presented in a graph

```
g <- data %>%
  separate_rows(elements, sep = ",") %>%
  graph_from_data_frame()

plot(g)
```

[image]

---

We can start from defining a custom function `f` like below

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(igraph)

f <- function(g, s) {
  mem <- membership(clusters(g))
  sapply(
    s,
    function(x) {
      clt <- mem[strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]]
      if (length(clt) > 1) {
        unlist(tapply(names(clt), clt, function(x) {
          if (length(x) > 1) {
            degree(g, mode = "in") == 0
            rt <- names(which(mem[names(which(degree(g, mode = "in") == 0))] == mem[x][1]))
            names(neighbors(g, x[which.min(distances(g, x, rt))], "in"))
          }
        }))
      } else {
        NA
      }
    }
  )
}
```

then run

```
df %>%
  mutate(Groups = f(
    data %>%
      separate_rows(elements, sep = ",") %>%
      graph_from_data_frame(),
    unique(var1)
  )[match(var1, unique(var1))])
```

and you will see

```
        date                  var1  Groups
1 2022-01-01                   cat    <NA>
2 2022-01-01                   cat    <NA>
3 2022-01-01                   cat    <NA>
4 2022-01-02 cat,Mother,bike,pasta  Family
5 2022-01-02 cat,Mother,bike,pasta  Family
6 2022-01-02 cat,Mother,bike,pasta  Family
7 2022-01-03              dog,bird animals
8 2022-01-03              dog,bird animals
9 2022-01-03              dog,bird animals
```